# is packbits compression another name for RLE

Tags: image, compression

iam  congfused over packbits compression. I used faststone image converter to convert a jpg image to tiff packbits compression. I then ran imagemagicks identify tool to look at the compression algorithm used and it stated that it was RLE. So does this mean that packbits and RLE refer to the same compression algorithm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  [packbits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackBits) is simply run-length encoding with a particular scheme for marking literal vs. repeated bytes.